# Hide "Places" or "Username" in File Chooser Dialog

Tags: xubuntu, files, security, gtk, dialog

## Background

Making a video-capture of a website demo; part of the demo requires uploading files.

## Problem

The username is displayed in the video, which is a security concern.

[image: Revealed Username]

## Question

How do you configure the Gtk file chooser to:

- hide the "Places" list;
- hide the username; or
- change the username to "Home"?

## Related

Related information:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625609/customizing-gtkfilechooser
- https://people.gnome.org/~federico/docs/file-chooser-extension-spec/index.html#scenario-lockdown

Comment: Are you sure that information goes through client side to server side? Is it really a security concern? Or ... Oh! You're actually doing a vidcap of a website???

Comment: Change the password of the user after you are done making the video.

Comment: @JustinAndrusk: How would changing the password help? Presumably nobody knows the password before they see the video, nor would they know the password after they see the video. Only the username would be known, which is what I want to avoid.